# Efficient querying on path u to v

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, tree

I have been solving a problem but couldn't get to an efficient solution.

**Problem Statement:**

> Given a tree with N vertices and N-1 edges. Each vertex v denotes a value given by C[v] where C[ ] is an array. For this tree we have to perform Q queries which is given below:
>
> A query is given by two integers u,v.  Let us define a value A which is given by the product of the values of all the nodes which lie on the simple path between u and v.
>
> More formally,if the simple path between u and v is [u,a,b...,v], then
>
> *A = C[u] * C[a] * C[b] * ... * C[v]*.
>
> For this query we need to output the number of divisors of A.
>
> **Constraints :**
>   1<=**N,Q**<=100000, 1<=**C[i]**<=1000000 for all 1<=**i**<=N.

**My approach** : Since the product could be very large, I am storing the prime factors and its count as answer.

I have first precomputed the LCA for the tree using binary lifting. Then I have defined a map< int, int >  for each node which stores the prime divisors and its count of the product from root upto the current node. This could be achieved by a simple DFS and a separate function for merging the maps

(Note: I am finding the prime factorization of a node using sieve in **O(LogN)**)

Then for each query of the type [u,v], I am finding the LCA (let's say *L*). Now I am subtracting the map of L from the map of u (Note: map of L will always be a subset of map of u) and similarly for node v.

Now I have all the prime factors and its count of the product.

Now simply using the result that for a number K = a^p * b^q * c^r..., the number of divisors D = (p+1) * (q+1) * (r+1)... we get out answer.

**Time Complexity Analysis :**

Let's define M as number of distinct primes up to 1000000.

DFS will run in O(N*M) time :
For each node, while combining the map the worst case  would be when all primes up to M would be present.

LCA pre-computation : O(NLogN) time

Sieve pre-computation : O(NLogLogN) time

Each query will run in O(M+LogN) time : O(LogN) for finding LCA and O(M) for subtracting the map to find the prime factors of the product.

So **Time Complexity:** *O(NLogN + NM + NLogLogN + QMLogN)*.

Now the issue is that in worst case M is of the order 50000. So this would blow up the time complexity. Is there any other efficient method?

Answer must be reported modulo 1e9+7

Comment: Don't delete your old question and ask the same question again. You'll get question-banned eventually. Like I said before this type of problem is more suitable for competitive programming forums such as Codeforces.

Comment: Maybe sorting the queries by the order or visiting of the nodes in a DFS, trying to use the result of the previous query to help finding the next?

Comment: @Daniel can you please be a bit more descriptive?

Comment: If you know the path between `u` to `v`, finding the path between `u` to `w` (where `w` is a child of `v`) is easy and fast, so letting those queries together is a good option. To choose how to sort, you can perform a DFS in the tree and save the index when you first find each node. This index can help you sorting the queries.